# How to use TableColumnModelListener to change the column color based on the reposition in java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, listener, tablecolumn

I have a table with four columns called `ID, Name, Subject, Marks`.
If the marks are below 35, then I am changing the `Marks` column colour to `RED` else `BLACK`.

Here, I have an issue where if I change the column position of `Marks` then it is becoming `BLACK' and the one which is currently there in the marks position is getting coloured.

I have tried by implementing the `TableColumnModelListener` and overridden columnMoved() method. When I try to get the column index as `tableModel.getColumnIndex("Marks")` it is still giving the previous position index but not the new one.

Is there a way to get the new column index by passing its name?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the colors in an implementation of [`TableCellRenderer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html) (possibly deriving from [`DefaultTableCellRenderer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableCellRenderer.html)). The `row` and `column` indexes reported in the [`getTableCellRendererComponent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html#getTableCellRendererComponent(javax.swing.JTable,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20int,%20int)) method are **view** indexes, not **model** indexes. You are most likely using a view index to index the model, or vice versa.

You can change the index from view to model by using any of the `JTable.convertXXXIndexToModel` methods, or from model to view by `JTable.convertXXXIndexToView` (where `XXX` is `Row` or `Column`). See the [`JTable` class documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) for more details.